# On dual boot if WiFi is turned OFF by ubuntu then after if one boots in windows WiFi is disabled and there is no way to enable it

Tags: dual-boot, wireless, bug-reporting

As the title says, I was using my ubuntu distro (20.04) and disabled the WiFi there for reasons (long story and irrelevant) went to settings and toggled the switch there to turn WiFi off.

Then when I finished what I was doing I turned the laptop off (shutdown from ubuntu) turned it on again selected Windows from Grup booted into windows, and WiFi was disabled (Ethernet via Lan cable works fine in both instances windows and ubuntu ) I tried to turn it On via the control panel settings... nothing, click airplane mode on and off, nothing... it simply can not be enabled in windows.

The only way to enable it is to boot to ubuntu again enable it from within ubuntu then shutdown (or restart both work) boot into windows **and then WiFi is enabled in windows when it boots**

Which essentially solves the problem but I still thing it is a bug mainly because of the inconvenience of having to boot into ubuntu in order re-enable the wifi if you have had it turned off whilst in ubuntu.

Laptop Acer predator Helios 300
Windows 10 / Ubuntu 20.04 dual boot

WiFi adapter is Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560, Mobo manufacturer CFL model Sienna_CFS (U3E1) chipset model intel ID3EC4 revision 07 southbridge model intel IDA30D revision 10

Bios version V 1.26

Comment: I suggest that you look into Fast Boot: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled

Comment: @chili555 nope your link describes a different thing I have 0 issues in the initialization process of the Wifi chip while booting into ubuntu...  the problem is the other way around and is not a initialization issue either since the driver and the device in general gets recognized by windows windows is just unable to turn it on.

Comment: Yes, I realize that. However, I think I'd at least experiment to see if the symptom is the same with Fast Boot on or off.

Comment: @chili555 I had already turned that feature off long before installing ubuntu